# 'use lib' can't find Perl module

Tags: perl

I'm on Windows 7, I downloaded a [CPAN module](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/XML-XPath-1.13/) called `XML::XPath`, and I want to use it in a script I wrote.

I cannot modify `@INC` on my machine, I cannot modify environmental variables on my machine, I cannot run `make` on my machine, and I cannot use a package manager on my machine.

So in order to use the module, I went to the CPAN website, downloaded the module's `.tar.gz` file, and unzipped it into a `lib` folder in my project. I did that because [this guide](https://perlmaven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations) suggested that I can use `use lib` in the context of my script to reference the downloaded module:

> Adding a use lib statement to the script will add the directory to @INC for that specific script. Regardless who and in what environment runs it.

My script is called `test.pl`.  I am trying to use the `XML::XPath` module to parse an XML file called `test.xml`.  Here is an example of my directory structure:

```
C:/
  → sandbox/
      test.pl
      test.xml
    → lib/
      → XML-XPath-1.13/
          XPath.pm
        → XPath/
            XMLParser.pm
            (etc.)
```

This is my `test.pl` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use lib qw("C:/sandbox/lib/XML-XPath-1.13");

my $xml_file = "C:/sandbox/test.xml";
my $result;

if (-f $xml_file) {
  $result = XML::XPath->new(filename => "$xml_file");
}
```

When I run this script with `perl test.pl`, the script fails with the following error:

> Can't locate object method "new" via package "XML::XPath" (perhaps you forgot to load "XML::XPath"?) at test.pl line 10.

Can I resolve this error with `use lib`?

**EDIT:**

When I add `use XML::XPath;` to my `test.pl` script, as such:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use lib qw("C:/sandbox/lib/XML-XPath-1.13");
```

I get an error like:

> Can't locate XML/XPath.pm in @INC

But as stated above, I cannot physically modify `@INC` or recompile Perl on my machine.

Comment: *perhaps you forgot to load "XML::XPath"?* - so where is your `use XML::XPath`? `use lib` only specifies the path where to look.

Comment: The directory structure of that module seems a bit weird, even if you add a `use XML::XPath;` it won't work. The version 1.13 is from 2003, but fortunately there are newer versions with a proper directory structure: (e.g. 1.42 from just a month ago).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have added the `use XML::XPath;` to my `test.pl` script (on line 4, underneath my `use lib` reference), but now I'm getting an error related to Perl looking in `@INC` for the script, and I cannot modify `@INC`. I have updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Digging a bit deeper, it seems that XML::XPath depends on the XML::Parser module which needs to be compiled. Unless you have a full Perl toolchain available (i.e. can compile C code and install modules), there's no way you can use this module. Just extracting a tarball only works for pure-Perl modules.

Comment: @amon That module does exist, it's located in in the `lib/XML-XPath-1.13/XPath/` directory in my project.  Can you elaborate on why can't I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not going to work. XML::XPath depends on the XML::Parser module which needs to be compiled. Since you do not have a complete toolchain with a C compiler available, there is no way you are getting this to run. You will have to search for a different way to handle your XML.

Just extracting a tarball only works when you have a pure-Perl module.

The easiest way to get a full Perl toolchain on Windows is to <del>install Linux</del> install the [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) distribution. There's even a ZIP edition and a portable edition that can be installed on a thumb drive, no admin privileges required.

---

Your more immediate problem is that XML::XPath in version 1.13 seems to be a shoddy module with an unusual directory layout. The package you are trying to load is at `XML-XPath-1.13/XPath.pm` but should be at `XML-XPath-1.13/lib/XML/XPath.pm`. Why?

When you say `use XML::XPath;` this does two things. First, Perl searches for a file `XML/XPath.pm` in all `@INC` directories. Assuming you have something like

```
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/lib/XML-XPath-1.13";
```

then perl would expect a file `PROJECT/lib/XML-XPath-1.13/XML/XPath.pm` which doesn't exist (where I'm using PROJECT as placeholder for the directory of your script).

Since the file `PROJECT/lib/XML-XPath-1.13/XPath.pm` does exist you could say `use XPath;`.

But then the second thing happens: The package is imported so that it can load subroutines or constants into your namespace. The `use`'d package name is now used as a class: `XPath->import`. However, the `XPath.pm` file does not contain the `XPath` package but the `XML::XPath` package, so there is no `XPath` class with an `import` method.

The import method call can be suppressed by providing an empty list in the use statement: `use XPath ();`.

Better than such hacks, you could use a more recent version of XML::XPath (version 1.13 is from 2003, but the newer version 1.42 is from 2007). Once you extract it you could `use lib "$FindBin::Bin/lib/XML-XPath-1.42/lib"` and then `use XML::XPath;`.

But this still won't work, because `XML::XPath` does `use XML::Parser` and you don't have that module installed. Now we are back to your main problem: XML::Parser needs to be compiled first because it contains a C extension, and also relies on an external library. Without a full toolchain you can't compile it.

Comment: Thank you very much the the clear and illustrative answer!  Sure enough, `use XPath` *does* resolve the initial `XPath` `@INC` error like you said - but interestingly, the same solution does not work one level deeper, on `XPath.pm` itself, with `use lib qw(...); use XMLParser;`.  So I believe that I am running into some complicated convention-based Perl package management issues.  Unfortunately, my being "dead to rights" makes StrawberryPerl not an option in my case, but this (and installing Linux) is a fine suggestion.

Comment: Re "*The easiest way to get a full Perl toolchain on Windows is to install Linux install the Strawberry Perl*", or by simply using `cpan` if you're using ActivePerl.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should properly install the module into `lib` rather than unzipping the distribution into `lib`.

Then, you'll need

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib "$RealBin/lib";

use XML::XPath qw( );
```

Comment: As stated in the question, I cannot use a proper package management utility such as PPM because of factors outside of my control.  I downloaded the physical `.pm` file though - shouldn't I theoretically be able to just use that?

Comment: I never mentioned `ppm` (or any other package management utility). I don't believe `ppm` lets you specify where you want to install the module. (If it did, then you could use `ppm` even though you mistakenly claimed otherwise..)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "you should properly install the module"?  I've only been using Perl for a few weeks now.  I would think that "properly installing the module" means to use a package manager, or `make`.  Both are unavailable to me.  Are you saying that it's not sufficient to simply download the package from CPAN as-is?

Comment: Re "*Both are unavailable to me.*", Clearly false since you can run arbitrary Perl code.

Comment: There is a trick: You could also use the exact same `perl` on a different machine to install the module, but instead of doing `make install` or `Build install`, you copy the contents of `blib` into `C:/Sandbox`. It's basically what `ppm` does.